# Retrieving a BLOB content from one table and storing it in another table

Tags: java, blob

I have a table with a blob field in it. I need to replicate the data of this table into another table. Could anyone tell me how to deal with blob data while replicating.

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonO=jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);  

    if(jsonO.has("file_content") && jsonO.getString("file_content")!="null")
    {
         PS.setBlob(4, (InputStream) jsonO.get("file_content"));  //Getting Error on this line
    }
}
```

Example of json data

```
{

    "territory_id": 10111,
    "file_name": "page.html",
    "file_size": 970,
    "file_content": "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",
    "creation_date": "2018-09-11T00:00:00Z",
    "created_by": "abc@gmail.com",
    "last_update_date": "2018-09-11T09:56:01Z"

}
```

Comment: What are you making that cast to `InputStream`?

Comment: I was just trying with some of the things. You can remove it.

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in a BLOB column? BLOB is for **binary** data which a JSON value is not. A CLOB data type (even JSON depending on your DBMS) would be a much better choice.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Handling of BLOB (or CLOB) columns depends greatly on the DBMS and JDBC driver being used.  Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
if(jsonO.has("file_content") && jsonO.getString("file_content")!="null"){
    String fileContent = jsonO.getString("file_content"); 
    PS.setBlob(4, new ByteInputStream(fileContent.getBytes("UTF-8")));  
}
```

or :

```
if(jsonO.has("file_content") && jsonO.getString("file_content")!="null"){
    String fileContent = jsonO.getString("file_content");
    PS.setBlob(4, new SerialBlob(fileContent.getBytes("UTF-8")));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anything goes wrong,Please send to, Because of your code annotation is this write

hypothesis do you want to save data to the other one table here's an example

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++)
{
JSONObject jsonO=jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);  

if(jsonO.has("file_content") && jsonO.getString("file_content")!="null")
{
     PS.setBlob(4, (InputStream) jsonO.get("file_content")); 
     JDBCUtil.saveDate(PS);//saveData method execute SQL 
}
}
```

I hope I can help you